# Web form scaffolding cant install on VS 2012, how can i install it properly for perform web form scaffolding in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

This is the error message I get in the time of installation

> 4/14/2015 5:14:19 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
>   4/14/2015 5:14:19 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

Please reply me any solution to solve this issue....

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: do you have this update?  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update

Comment: @InvernoMuto im using Visual studio 2012